# cmake not generating Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp header for Xerces 3.2.5 build on windows

Tags: cmake, xerces, xerces-c

I am attempting the build the Xerces 3.2.5 library [from source](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/download.cgi) for windows per [these instructions.](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html).

My compiler is Visual Studio 2019. The version is mandated by the application for which I am ultimately developing code for as Its APIs are only certified for that version of VS.

The `cmake --build` step fails because multiple files cannot find the `Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp`. That file is indeed missing although there is both a `Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp.cmake.in` and a `Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp.in` which I presume are used by ~something~ in the build chain to generate the missing header.

The failing source files indicate as much,

```
//  If the next line generates an error then you haven't run ./configure
#include    <xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp>
```

however `configure` is a shell script that doesn't run under windows.

**STEPS TAKEN:**

1. Downloaded the xerces-c-3.2.5.zip and expanded it into a folder.
2. opened a VS 2019 command prompt and cd'd to that directory
3. `mkdir build` / `cd build`

   - per the Windows examples in the build instructions (link above).
4. `cmake -Wno-dev -DPROJECT_VERSION=3.2.5 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=G:\libs ..\src`

   - I had to add the `-DPROJECT_VERSION=3.2.5` to the example command otherwise I got errors because the `write_basic_package_version_file()` command in CMakeLists.txt was missing the version. It is purely a SWAG that 3.2.5 was in fact the correct value to pass.
5. `cmake --build . --config Debug`

   - This is the failing command.

Typical error message:

```
C:\Dev\xerces-c-3.2.5\src\xercesc/util/XercesDefs.hpp(46,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I assume there is something I have to do to have cmake generate the missing header file but I do not know what that is.